# Find Item by key without using eval

Tags: php, arrays, eval

I know that `eval()` is a horrible thing to use, but I couldn't think of a better way to do this.

I have the following method which I want to use to delete items from a multidimensional array, and it should delete the item if it exists.

```
public function delete(){
    $keys = func_get_args();
    $str  = "";
    foreach($keys as $key){
        $str .= "['$key']";
    }
    eval("if(isset(\$_SESSION$str)){unset(\$_SESSION$str);}");
}
```

To use it I would make a call like so:

```
$obj->delete("one", "two", "three");
```

which would be the equivalent to this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["one"]["two"]["three"])){
    unset($_SESSION["one"]["two"]["three"]);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this than using `eval()`?

Comment: you can do it with a loop. Though I don't understand why you need such a method - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: How would a loop work? an undefined number of values can be passed to the method...

Comment: that's exactly why you need a loop. or recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will achieve what you want:

```
function delete(){
    $keys = func_get_args();

    $ref = &$_SESSION;
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeOf($keys)-1; $x++) {
        $ref = &$ref[$keys[$x]];
    }
    unset($ref[$keys[sizeOf($keys)-1]]);
    unset($ref);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that works, I was also able to use this strategy on another method that works checks to see if it exists. I am not 100% sure how that reference part works, could you explain it a little more?

Comment: Since you wanted to delete the last element in the array, all this does is keep going up your array tree until it at the last element, then removes the element and also removes the reference. so if you had `[ 'a' => [ 'b' => [ 'c' => 123 ] ] ]` it's actually selecting `['a']['b']` and from there it can `unset(['a']['b']['c']);`

Answer (score 4):

There is a function like that in [Ouzo Goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies):

```
Arrays::removeNestedKey($_SESSION, ['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

If you don't want to include the lib, you can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo/blob/master/src/Ouzo/Goodies/Utilities/Arrays.php) and grab the function itself:

```
public static function removeNestedKey(array &$array, array $keys)
{
    $key = array_shift($keys);
    if (count($keys) == 0) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    } else {
        self::removeNestedKey($array[$key], $keys);
    }
}
```